Use netplan to have a failover wifi interface between two wifi adapters
I have two wifi adapters on my devices, one built in and the other requiring drivers.
I use unattended upgrades and have been having issues when a kernel upgrade happens the drivers for the device fails and then needs to be compiled manually with the new kernel header files even though I have setup dkms (as the internet drops no new header files can be downloaded). The onboard interface does work but has much weaker signal to use all of the time.
So I was looking for a way where I can set a static ip on both devices with the same address and route but only enable one if the other fails. I setup a bash script as follows:
#!/bin/bash

PRIMARY_IFACE="wlx1"
SECONDARY_IFACE="wlan0"
CHECK_INTERVAL=10

while true; do
    # Check if the primary interface is connected
    if iw dev ${PRIMARY_IFACE} link | grep -q "Not connected"; then
        # If the primary is not connected, try to reconnect
        ip link set ${PRIMARY_IFACE} up
        sleep 5  # Give some time for connection establishment
        
        # Check if the primary is now connected
        if iw dev ${PRIMARY_IFACE} link | grep -q "Not connected"; then
            # If still not connected, switch to the secondary interface
            ip link set ${SECONDARY_IFACE} up
            ip link set ${PRIMARY_IFACE} down
        fi
    fi

    # Sleep for the check interval
    sleep ${CHECK_INTERVAL}
done

I was intending to bring up wlan0 if wlx1 was down or not present, does anyone have any ideas on how best to do this as currently with netplan both interface try to connect at once?

I've written a bash script to help with this: https://github.com/waltinator/net-o-matic It watches the connection, and when the connection drops, does a user-specified thing to try to reconnect or do something else.
